# 'vscode ssh Acquiring local install lock: T/vscode-remote-ssh-7b..8f-install.lock". "Acquiring lock on /mnt/users/.vscode-server/bin/..lock.root..."

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

when I use ssh to connect to remote sever though VScode, there are something wrong, the log is showing blow, actually I have tried several method to fix, such as rm the "..lock.." file, while the file will auto-generated again, and I also set some vscode extension setting, and “factory reset” as vscode was able to connect to the remote server at first, until I didn't know what operation it was going through。so sad o(TヘTo)

```
[15:36:33.593] Log Level: 2
[15:36:33.593] remote-ssh@0.80.0
[15:36:33.593] darwin arm64
[15:36:33.596] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+10.10.2.22", attempt 1
[15:36:33.596] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": true
[15:36:33.596] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[15:36:33.596] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[15:36:33.596] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[15:36:33.596] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": true
[15:36:33.596] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[15:36:33.597] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[15:36:33.597] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[15:36:33.597] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[15:36:33.597] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[15:36:33.597] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[15:36:33.597] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[15:36:33.598] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[15:36:33.598] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[15:36:33.608] SSH Resolver called for host: 10.10.2.22
[15:36:33.608] Setting up SSH remote "10.10.2.22"
[15:36:33.609] Acquiring local install lock: /var/folders/h9/x773zj9d2s950qbc71tt84lr0000gn/T/vscode-remote-ssh-7b87841f-install.lock
[15:36:33.610] Looking for existing server data file at /Users/edy/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-7b87841f-c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5-0.80.0/data.json
[15:36:33.610] Using commit id "c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5" and quality "stable" for server
[15:36:33.611] Install and start server if needed
[15:36:33.613] PATH: /Users/edy/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/edy/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
[15:36:33.613] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[15:36:33.615] > OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 2.8.3

[15:36:33.617] askpass server listening on /var/folders/h9/x773zj9d2s950qbc71tt84lr0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-10db74a0c1ca4c7b7b971483ece99138c59afd8c.sock
[15:36:33.617] Spawning local server with {"serverId":1,"ipcHandlePath":"/var/folders/h9/x773zj9d2s950qbc71tt84lr0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-5f94aae6ffcc5dd14f668e59594e7ea397f94bc2.sock","sshCommand":"ssh","sshArgs":["-v","-T","-D","50181","-o","ConnectTimeout=20","10.10.2.22"],"serverDataFolderName":".vscode-server","dataFilePath":"/Users/edy/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-7b87841f-c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5-0.80.0/data.json"}
[15:36:33.617] Local server env: {"SSH_AUTH_SOCK":"/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.zenXhDBdx6/Listeners","SHELL":"/bin/zsh","DISPLAY":"1","ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1","SSH_ASKPASS":"/Users/edy/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.80.0/out/local-server/askpass.sh","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE":"/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_EXTRA_ARGS":"--ms-enable-electron-run-as-node","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN":"/Users/edy/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.80.0/out/askpass-main.js","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE":"/var/folders/h9/x773zj9d2s950qbc71tt84lr0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-10db74a0c1ca4c7b7b971483ece99138c59afd8c.sock"}
[15:36:33.618] Spawned 26541
[15:36:33.680] > local-server-1> Spawned ssh, pid=26547
[15:36:33.681] stderr> OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 2.8.3
[15:36:37.481] stderr> debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:3x0pHQRoRvaWEO1R2b+zJmKZEedEa++PxJvtjXewBYs
[15:36:40.874] stderr> Authenticated to 10.10.2.22 ([10.10.2.22]:23453).
[15:36:43.331] > Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-142-generic x86_64)
> 
> * Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com
> * Management: https://landscape.canonical.com
> * Support: https://ubuntu.com/advantage
[15:36:43.336] > ready: 6e87d617dce1
[15:36:43.337] stderr> /etc/profile: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
[15:36:43.337] stderr> /etc/profile: line 1: ` /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))'
[15:36:43.381] > Linux 4.4.0-142-generic #168-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 16 21:00:45 UTC 2019
[15:36:43.381] Platform: linux
[15:36:43.426] > /bin/bash
[15:36:43.426] Shell: bash
[15:36:43.426] Creating bash subshell inside "bash"
[15:36:43.496] > bash version: 4.3.48(1)-release
[15:36:43.779] > bash version: 4.3.48(1)-release
[15:36:43.829] > 6e87d617dce1: running
[15:36:43.921] > Acquiring lock on /tmp/vscode-remote-lock.root.c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5
[15:36:43.925] > Found existing installation at /mnt/users/.vscode-server/bin/c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5...
> Checking /mnt/users/.vscode-server/.c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5.log and /mnt/users/.vscode-server/.c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5.pid for a running server
[15:36:43.926] > Looking for server with pid: 118743
[15:36:43.935] > Found running server...
[15:36:43.937] > 
> *
[15:36:43.937] > * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products,
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> *
> 
[15:36:43.952] > Checking server status on socket /tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470 with curl
[15:36:43.958] > 6e87d617dce1: start
> SSH_AUTH_SOCK====
> DISPLAY====
> webUiAccessToken====
> listeningOn==/tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470==
> osReleaseId==ubuntu==
> arch==x86_64==
> tmpDir==/tmp==
> platform==linux==
> unpackResult====
> didLocalDownload==0==
> downloadTime====
> installTime====
> extInstallTime====
> serverStartTime====
> connectionToken==a1aa1111-a111-1111-1a11-1a1a11a11111==
> 6e87d617dce1: end
[15:36:43.959] Received install output: 
SSH_AUTH_SOCK====
DISPLAY====
webUiAccessToken====
listeningOn==/tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470==
osReleaseId==ubuntu==
arch==x86_64==
tmpDir==/tmp==
platform==linux==
unpackResult====
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime====
installTime====
extInstallTime====
serverStartTime====
connectionToken==a1aa1111-a111-1111-1a11-1a1a11a11111==

[15:36:43.959] Remote server is listening on /tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470
[15:36:43.959] Parsed server configuration: {"serverConfiguration":{"remoteListeningOn":{"socketPath":"/tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470"},"osReleaseId":"ubuntu","arch":"x86_64","webUiAccessToken":"","sshAuthSock":"","display":"","tmpDir":"/tmp","platform":"linux","connectionToken":"a1aa1111-a111-1111-1a11-1a1a11a11111"},"installUnpackCode":""}
[15:36:43.961] Persisting server connection details to /Users/edy/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-7b87841f-c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5-0.80.0/data.json
[15:36:43.965] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -L 127.0.0.1:50185:/tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470 -o ConnectTimeout=20 '10.10.2.22' bash
[15:36:43.965] Spawning tunnel with: ssh -T -L 127.0.0.1:50185:/tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470 -o ConnectTimeout=20 '10.10.2.22' bash << 'EOSSH'
echo SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK && echo -e 'Connected to SSH Host - Please do not close this terminal' && while true; do sleep 180; echo -n ' '; done
EOSSH
[15:36:47.389] > SSH_AUTH_SOCK=
> Connected to SSH Host - Please do not close this terminal
[15:36:47.389] Spawned SSH tunnel between local port 50185 and remote target /tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470
[15:36:47.389] Waiting for ssh tunnel to be ready
[15:36:47.391] Tunneled /tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470 to local port 50185
[15:36:47.391] Resolved "ssh-remote+10.10.2.22" to "127.0.0.1:50185"
[15:36:47.400] ------



[15:37:09.004] ------



[15:37:09.004] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+10.10.2.22", attempt 2, (Reconnection)
[15:37:09.007] SSH Resolver called for host: 10.10.2.22
[15:37:09.007] Setting up SSH remote "10.10.2.22"
[15:37:09.008] Acquiring local install lock: /var/folders/h9/x773zj9d2s950qbc71tt84lr0000gn/T/vscode-remote-ssh-7b87841f-install.lock
[15:37:09.008] Looking for existing server data file at /Users/edy/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-7b87841f-c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5-0.80.0/data.json
[15:37:09.009] Found local server running: {"remoteListeningOn":{"socketPath":"/tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470"},"osReleaseId":"ubuntu","arch":"x86_64","webUiAccessToken":"","sshAuthSock":"","display":"","tmpDir":"/tmp","platform":"linux","connectionToken":"a1aa1111-a111-1111-1a11-1a1a11a11111","pid":26541,"ipcHandlePath":"/var/folders/h9/x773zj9d2s950qbc71tt84lr0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-5f94aae6ffcc5dd14f668e59594e7ea397f94bc2.sock","socksPort":50181,"startupTime":1653982593618}
[15:37:09.009] Running server is stale. Ignoring
[15:37:09.009] Using commit id "c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5" and quality "stable" for server
[15:37:09.011] Install and start server if needed
[15:37:09.014] askpass server listening on /var/folders/h9/x773zj9d2s950qbc71tt84lr0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-8de95c5fed60e04938c93496990b52b7fe77cf80.sock
[15:37:09.014] Spawning local server with {"serverId":2,"ipcHandlePath":"/var/folders/h9/x773zj9d2s950qbc71tt84lr0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-ae668d2104777f19d11bf584b8e7e4fe7cf92f3d.sock","sshCommand":"ssh","sshArgs":["-v","-T","-D","50193","-o","ConnectTimeout=20","10.10.2.22"],"serverDataFolderName":".vscode-server","dataFilePath":"/Users/edy/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-7b87841f-c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5-0.80.0/data.json"}
[15:37:09.014] Local server env: {"SSH_AUTH_SOCK":"/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.zenXhDBdx6/Listeners","SHELL":"/bin/zsh","DISPLAY":"1","ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1","SSH_ASKPASS":"/Users/edy/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.80.0/out/local-server/askpass.sh","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE":"/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_EXTRA_ARGS":"--ms-enable-electron-run-as-node","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN":"/Users/edy/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.80.0/out/askpass-main.js","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE":"/var/folders/h9/x773zj9d2s950qbc71tt84lr0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-8de95c5fed60e04938c93496990b52b7fe77cf80.sock"}
[15:37:09.015] Spawned 26722
[15:37:09.092] > local-server-2> Spawned ssh, pid=26728
[15:37:09.094] stderr> OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 2.8.3
[15:37:13.087] stderr> debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:3x0pHQRoRvaWEO1R2b+zJmKZEedEa++PxJvtjXewBYs
[15:37:13.142] > local-server-1> Timed out
[15:37:13.147] Local server exit: 0
[15:37:13.864] stderr> Authenticated to 10.10.2.22 ([10.10.2.22]:23453).
[15:37:14.298] > Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-142-generic x86_64)
> 
> * Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com
> * Management: https://landscape.canonical.com
> * Support: https://ubuntu.com/advantage
[15:37:14.299] stderr> /etc/profile: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
[15:37:14.299] stderr> /etc/profile: line 1: ` /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))'
[15:37:14.340] > ready: 961437fb9797
[15:37:14.663] > Linux 4.4.0-142-generic #168-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 16 21:00:45 UTC 2019
[15:37:14.664] Platform: linux
[15:37:14.972] > /bin/bash
[15:37:14.973] Shell: bash
[15:37:14.973] Creating bash subshell inside "bash"
[15:37:15.233] > bash version: 4.3.48(1)-release
[15:37:15.234] > bash version: 4.3.48(1)-release
> bash version: 4.3.48(1)-release
> bash version: 4.3.48(1)-release
> bash version: 4.3.48(1)-release
[15:37:15.273] > bash version: 4.3.48(1)-release
[15:37:15.412] > 961437fb9797: running
[15:37:15.689] > Acquiring lock on /tmp/vscode-remote-lock.root.c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5
> Found existing installation at /mnt/users/.vscode-server/bin/c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5...
[15:37:15.690] > Checking /mnt/users/.vscode-server/.c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5.log and /mnt/users/.vscode-server/.c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5.pid for a running server
> Looking for server with pid: 118743
> Found running server...
> 
> *
> * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products,
[15:37:15.690] > * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> *
> 
> Checking server status on socket /tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470 with curl
[15:37:15.691] > 961437fb9797: start
[15:37:15.731] > SSH_AUTH_SOCK====
> DISPLAY====
> webUiAccessToken====
> listeningOn==/tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470==
> osReleaseId==ubuntu==
> arch==x86_64==
> tmpDir==/tmp==
> platform==linux==
> unpackResult====
> didLocalDownload==0==
> downloadTime====
> installTime====
> extInstallTime====
> serverStartTime====
> connectionToken==a1aa1111-a111-1111-1a11-1a1a11a11111==
> 961437fb9797: end
[15:37:15.732] Received install output: SSH_AUTH_SOCK====
DISPLAY====
webUiAccessToken====
listeningOn==/tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470==
osReleaseId==ubuntu==
arch==x86_64==
tmpDir==/tmp==
platform==linux==
unpackResult====
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime====
installTime====
extInstallTime====
serverStartTime====
connectionToken==a1aa1111-a111-1111-1a11-1a1a11a11111==

[15:37:15.732] Remote server is listening on /tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470
[15:37:15.733] Parsed server configuration: {"serverConfiguration":{"remoteListeningOn":{"socketPath":"/tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470"},"osReleaseId":"ubuntu","arch":"x86_64","webUiAccessToken":"","sshAuthSock":"","display":"","tmpDir":"/tmp","platform":"linux","connectionToken":"a1aa1111-a111-1111-1a11-1a1a11a11111"},"installUnpackCode":""}
[15:37:15.735] Persisting server connection details to /Users/edy/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-7b87841f-c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5-0.80.0/data.json
[15:37:15.740] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -L 127.0.0.1:50196:/tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470 -o ConnectTimeout=20 '10.10.2.22' bash
[15:37:15.740] Spawning tunnel with: ssh -T -L 127.0.0.1:50196:/tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470 -o ConnectTimeout=20 '10.10.2.22' bash << 'EOSSH'
echo SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK && echo -e 'Connected to SSH Host - Please do not close this terminal' && while true; do sleep 180; echo -n ' '; done
EOSSH
[15:37:19.729] > SSH_AUTH_SOCK=
> Connected to SSH Host - Please do not close this terminal
[15:37:19.729] Spawned SSH tunnel between local port 50196 and remote target /tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470
[15:37:19.729] Waiting for ssh tunnel to be ready
[15:37:19.730] Tunneled /tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470 to local port 50196
[15:37:19.730] Resolved "ssh-remote+10.10.2.22" to "127.0.0.1:50196"
[15:37:19.732] ------



[15:37:40.658] ------



[15:37:40.658] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+10.10.2.22", attempt 3, (Reconnection)
[15:37:40.660] SSH Resolver called for host: 10.10.2.22
[15:37:40.660] Setting up SSH remote "10.10.2.22"
[15:37:40.664] Acquiring local install lock: /var/folders/h9/x773zj9d2s950qbc71tt84lr0000gn/T/vscode-remote-ssh-7b87841f-install.lock
[15:37:40.665] Looking for existing server data file at /Users/edy/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-7b87841f-c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5-0.80.0/data.json
[15:37:40.665] Found local server running: {"remoteListeningOn":{"socketPath":"/tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470"},"osReleaseId":"ubuntu","arch":"x86_64","webUiAccessToken":"","sshAuthSock":"","display":"","tmpDir":"/tmp","platform":"linux","connectionToken":"a1aa1111-a111-1111-1a11-1a1a11a11111","pid":26722,"ipcHandlePath":"/var/folders/h9/x773zj9d2s950qbc71tt84lr0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-ae668d2104777f19d11bf584b8e7e4fe7cf92f3d.sock","socksPort":50193,"startupTime":1653982629015}
[15:37:40.665] Running server is stale. Ignoring
[15:37:40.665] Using commit id "c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5" and quality "stable" for server
[15:37:40.667] Install and start server if needed
[15:37:40.668] askpass server listening on /var/folders/h9/x773zj9d2s950qbc71tt84lr0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-618c8c6b9c7ec9fc5ac0077b6f0a3f7beaf4219a.sock
[15:37:40.669] Spawning local server with {"serverId":3,"ipcHandlePath":"/var/folders/h9/x773zj9d2s950qbc71tt84lr0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-6164deba0a33a2bc70c65e3eb241ea3981b5bfd5.sock","sshCommand":"ssh","sshArgs":["-v","-T","-D","50204","-o","ConnectTimeout=20","10.10.2.22"],"serverDataFolderName":".vscode-server","dataFilePath":"/Users/edy/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-7b87841f-c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5-0.80.0/data.json"}
[15:37:40.669] Local server env: {"SSH_AUTH_SOCK":"/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.zenXhDBdx6/Listeners","SHELL":"/bin/zsh","DISPLAY":"1","ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1","SSH_ASKPASS":"/Users/edy/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.80.0/out/local-server/askpass.sh","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE":"/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_EXTRA_ARGS":"--ms-enable-electron-run-as-node","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN":"/Users/edy/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.80.0/out/askpass-main.js","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE":"/var/folders/h9/x773zj9d2s950qbc71tt84lr0000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-618c8c6b9c7ec9fc5ac0077b6f0a3f7beaf4219a.sock"}
[15:37:40.670] Spawned 26737
[15:37:40.751] > local-server-3> Spawned ssh, pid=26743
[15:37:40.752] stderr> OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 2.8.3
[15:37:44.267] stderr> debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:3x0pHQRoRvaWEO1R2b+zJmKZEedEa++PxJvtjXewBYs
[15:37:44.540] > local-server-2> Timed out
[15:37:44.545] Local server exit: 0
[15:37:45.078] stderr> Authenticated to 10.10.2.22 ([10.10.2.22]:23453).
[15:37:45.206] > Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-142-generic x86_64)
> 
> * Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com
> * Management: https://landscape.canonical.com
> * Support: https://ubuntu.com/advantage
[15:37:45.208] stderr> /etc/profile: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
[15:37:45.208] stderr> /etc/profile: line 1: ` /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))'
[15:37:45.248] > ready: 2cfae9a9c876
[15:37:45.293] > Linux 4.4.0-142-generic #168-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 16 21:00:45 UTC 2019
[15:37:45.294] Platform: linux
[15:37:45.337] > /bin/bash
[15:37:45.338] Shell: bash
[15:37:45.338] Creating bash subshell inside "bash"
[15:37:45.383] > bash version: 4.3.48(1)-release
[15:37:48.371] > 2cfae9a9c876: running
[15:37:48.372] > Acquiring lock on /tmp/vscode-remote-lock.root.c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5
> Found existing installation at /mnt/users/.vscode-server/bin/c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5...
> Checking /mnt/users/.vscode-server/.c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5.log and /mnt/users/.vscode-server/.c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5.pid for a running server
> Looking for server with pid: 118743
[15:37:48.413] > Found running server...
> 
> *
> * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products,
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> *
> 
> Checking server status on socket /tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470 with curl
> 2cfae9a9c876: start
> SSH_AUTH_SOCK====
> DISPLAY====
> webUiAccessToken====
> listeningOn==/tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470==
> osReleaseId==ubuntu==
> arch==x86_64==
> tmpDir==/tmp==
> platform==linux==
> unpackResult====
> didLocalDownload==0==
> downloadTime====
> installTime====
> extInstallTime====
> serverStartTime====
> connectionToken==a1aa1111-a111-1111-1a11-1a1a11a11111==
> 2cfae9a9c876: end
[15:37:48.414] Received install output: 
SSH_AUTH_SOCK====
DISPLAY====
webUiAccessToken====
listeningOn==/tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470==
osReleaseId==ubuntu==
arch==x86_64==
tmpDir==/tmp==
platform==linux==
unpackResult====
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime====
installTime====
extInstallTime====
serverStartTime====
connectionToken==a1aa1111-a111-1111-1a11-1a1a11a11111==

[15:37:48.414] Remote server is listening on /tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470
[15:37:48.414] Parsed server configuration: {"serverConfiguration":{"remoteListeningOn":{"socketPath":"/tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470"},"osReleaseId":"ubuntu","arch":"x86_64","webUiAccessToken":"","sshAuthSock":"","display":"","tmpDir":"/tmp","platform":"linux","connectionToken":"a1aa1111-a111-1111-1a11-1a1a11a11111"},"installUnpackCode":""}
[15:37:48.415] Persisting server connection details to /Users/edy/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-7b87841f-c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5-0.80.0/data.json
[15:37:48.421] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -L 127.0.0.1:50206:/tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470 -o ConnectTimeout=20 '10.10.2.22' bash
[15:37:48.422] Spawning tunnel with: ssh -T -L 127.0.0.1:50206:/tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470 -o ConnectTimeout=20 '10.10.2.22' bash << 'EOSSH'
echo SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK && echo -e 'Connected to SSH Host - Please do not close this terminal' && while true; do sleep 180; echo -n ' '; done
EOSSH
[15:37:53.782] > SSH_AUTH_SOCK=
> Connected to SSH Host - Please do not close this terminal
[15:37:53.782] Spawned SSH tunnel between local port 50206 and remote target /tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470
[15:37:53.783] Waiting for ssh tunnel to be ready
[15:37:53.784] Tunneled /tmp/vscode-ssh-remote-server-sock-1653979470 to local port 50206
[15:37:53.784] Resolved "ssh-remote+10.10.2.22" to "127.0.0.1:50206"
[15:37:53.789] ------
```

Hi, when I use ssh to connect to remote sever though VScode, there are something wrong, the log is showing blow, actually I have tried several method to fix, such as rm the "..lock.." file, while the file will auto-generated again, and I also set some vscode extension setting, and “factory reset” as vscode was able to connect to the remote server at first, until I didn't know what operation it was going through。so sad o(TヘTo)

Comment: Oh， forget to say，I can ssh to remote by terminal, and my other device can connect to remote sever by ssh through vscode......

Comment: did you end up getting this solved?